# C# passing object between class is null

Tags: c#

Im trying to write a C# application that parses an XML file and returns the selected node through a function. These are my classes:

XmlDocumentParser.cs

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace Namespace1
{
    public class XmlDocumentParser
    {
        // This is a private instance variable that cannot be reassigned
        private readonly XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        private string udc = "urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Document:xsd:schema:01.12";
        private string udct = "urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:DocumentType:xsd:codelist:01.13";
        private string tns = "urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:PurchaseOrderRequest:xsd:schema:02.05";
        private string dp = "urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:xsd:schema:02.29";

        //This is the constructor
        public XmlDocumentParser(string documentPath)
        {
            document.Load(documentPath);
            XmlNode Root = document.DocumentElement;
            XmlNamespaceManager Nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
            Nsmgr.AddNamespace("udc", udc); 
            Nsmgr.AddNamespace("udct", udct);
            Nsmgr.AddNamespace("tns", tns);
        }

        // This is a public property that can only be read and not set
        public XmlNode Root { private set; get; }
        public XmlNode Nsmgr {private set; get; }
    }
}
```

PORReader.cs

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;


namespace Namespace1 {
    public class PORReader {
    private readonly XmlNode root;
    private readonly XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr;
    public PORReader(string documentPath){ 
        var xmlDocumentParser = new XmlDocumentParser(documentPath);
        var root = xmlDocumentParser.Root;  
    }

    public object getPurchaseOrder(){

        XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode(
                "descendant::tns:PurchaseOrder/udc:BusinessDocumentReference[udct:DocumentType='SAO']/udc:Identifier", nsmgr);
        return returnNode(node.InnerXml);
    }

        private object returnNode(object node){
            if (node != null) {
                return node;
            } else {
                return "Error in Node";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace Namespace1
{
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args){
            // This will reside in the reader classes
            var xmlDocumentParser = new XmlDocumentParser("/Users/moorel/Desktop/Projects/C#/O2/DummyFiles/SupplyChainSourceFiles/POR/POR_SALES_8307_20180201164154.xml");
            var root = xmlDocumentParser.Root;
            var nsmgr = xmlDocumentParser.Nsmgr;
        }
    }
}
```

And my test is:

```
namespace Namespace1 {
    using NUnit.Framework;

    [TestFixture]
    public class PORReaderTest {
        [Test]
        public void getPurchaseOrder(){

            PORReader reader = new PORReader("/Users/moorel/Desktop/Projects/C#/O2/DummyFiles/SupplyChainSourceFiles/POR/POR_SALES_8307_20180201164154.xml");
            Assert.AreEqual(reader.getPurchaseOrder(), "aa036E31tc63qjPfIMJ");
        }
    }
}
```

So, the document path to the xml is correct and the value ""aa036E31tc63qjPfIMJ" is present in the xml, however the test is erroring with the message `System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

In class `PORReader` the value of `root` is null, and I need it to be the object thats imported from `XmlDocumentParser`. I'm unfamiliar with C# classes so any help would be much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you implement in C# if you're unfamiliar with it? Without seeing the XML document, we probably can't help much.

Comment: You need to show us the XmlDocument you're trying to parse.

Comment: unfortunately i cant share the XML document, but the xpath works fine and the value is present in the test. I have an issue with passing the root object from XmlDocumentParser class to PORReader class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I see.

You're not acutally doing anything in the `XmlDocumentParser` constructor.

This line:

```
XmlNode Root = document.DocumentElement;
```

does not assign to the `Root` property, it creates a local variable named `Root`. Change it to

```
Root = document.DocumentElement;
```

and see if that helps.
Also it would probably be wise to make a run with the debugger and see if everythings correct, e.g. if `document.DocumentElement` actually returns the root you're looking for.

EDIT:

I'm blind.

You have the exact same error in `PORReader`.

```
var root = xmlDocumentParser.Root;
```

This doesn't assign to your `private readonly` field, but creates a local variable. Change to:

```
root = xmlDocumentParser.Root;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I made those edits but the error message ` System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ` still persists :/

Comment: Have you run the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

**XmlDocumentParser.cs**

```
namespace Namespace1
{
    public class XmlDocumentParser
    {
        // This is a private instance variable that cannot be reassigned
        private readonly XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        private string udc = "urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:Document:xsd:schema:01.12";
        private string udct = "urn:rosettanet:specification:universal:DocumentType:xsd:codelist:01.13";
        private string tns = "urn:rosettanet:specification:interchange:PurchaseOrderRequest:xsd:schema:02.05";
        private string dp = "urn:rosettanet:specification:domain:Procurement:xsd:schema:02.29";

        //This is the constructor
        public XmlDocumentParser(string documentPath)
        {
            document.Load(documentPath);
            Root = document.DocumentElement as XmlNode;
            Nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
            Nsmgr.AddNamespace("udc", udc);
            Nsmgr.AddNamespace("udct", udct);
            Nsmgr.AddNamespace("tns", tns);
        }

        // This is a public property that can only be read and not set
        public XmlNode Root { get; }
        public XmlNamespaceManager Nsmgr { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed XmlDocumentParser.cs accordingly and the error still persists

Comment: what does the stacktrace say?

Comment: ` Error Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Stack Trace:
   at Namespce1.PORReader.getPurchaseOrder() in /Users/moorel/Desktop/Projects/C#/O2/ReportingXML/PORReader.cs:line 18
   at Namespace1.PORReaderTest.getPurchaseOrder() in /Users/moorel/Desktop/Projects/C#/O2/ReportingXML/PORReaderTest.cs:line 11`